# JSF 1.2 facelets custom component

Tags: jsf, facelets, custom-component

I am trying to develop custom control in JSF 1.2 (using facelets).

I followed steps from different tutorials (defining .tld, taglib.xml, registered component in faces-config.xml and implementing UIComponent (component renders itself) and UIComponentELTag classes) and my component is rendered, I have value bound to it, but attributes I defined for that tag are ignored. I logged various methods in Tag class and noticed that none of the methods is ever called.

What am I missing? Is there a reason Tag handler class is never invoked?

Thanks in advance.

My taglib.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC 
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
  "java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib> 
  <namespace>dynamissoft.com/entities/ui</namespace>
  <tag>
    <tag-name>legalEntityView</tag-name>
    <component>
      <component-type>rs.bozic.wastemanager.LegalEntityView</component-type>
    </component>
  </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Comment: Please post your xxx.taglib.xml file.

Comment: My taglib.xml file is:
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
      "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
      "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">

        <facelet-taglib>
            <namespace>http://www.dynamissoft.com/entities/ui</namespace>
                <tag>
                    <tag-name>legalEntityView</tag-name>
                    <component>
                        <component-type>rs.bozic.wastemanager.LegalEntityView</component-type>
                    </component>
              </tag>
        </facelet-taglib>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried creating a custom component using facelets (xml only). That's the most easy way, using facelets, usually, the different java classes aren't needed anymore.

Very rough overview:

- Create facelet xml file (like myComponent.xhtml)
- Register in the facelet inside a taglib (which in turn should be defined in the web.xml)
- Optionally, create some support beans in Java

You can pass values/beans to your component using normal tag paramets:

Using the component

Inside the component

Param1 is just printed: #{myParam2}
Param2 used as value for table

...

There are excellent tutorials on [Google](http://www.google.nl/search?q=custom+component+facelets), like the one from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/).

If possible, consider using JSF 2.0. Facelets are integrated, and you have more flexibility to create your custom components. I created a blog posting a while ago on that: http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2010/02/08/jsf-2-0/ (or Google yourself)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I have tried, but it required me to do some extra work (registering resources on WAS CE, etc.) which I tried to avoid.
Anyway, I did it, so I moved to using .xhtml files for creating components and now it works.
Still, I don't know what happened before :-(.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand Gerbrand's answer a bit, here's a procedure for a simple Facelets-compatible component. It renders a `span` tag that wraps a text specified via component's `text` attribute.

1. First create the component class (in our case it's just a flavour of
   `UIOutput`):

   ```
     package sample.mytag;

     import java.io.IOException;
     import javax.faces.component.UIOutput;
     import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
     import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;

     public class SpanComponent extends UIOutput{            
       private String text;
       @Override
       public Object saveState(FacesContext context) {
         Object values[] = new Object[2];
         values[0] = super.saveState(context);
         values[1] = target;
         return ((Object) (values));
       }

       @Override
       public void restoreState(FacesContext context, Object state) {
         Object values[] = (Object[])state;
         super.restoreState(context, values[0]);
         target = (String)values[1];
       }

       public String getText() {
         return text;
       }

       public void setText(String text) {
         this.text = text;
       }

       @Override
       public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
         ResponseWriter writer=context.getResponseWriter();
         writer.startElement("span", component);
         writer.writeAttribute("id", id, null);
         writer.writeText(text, null);
         writer.endElement("span");
         writer.flush();                
       }

       @Override
       public String getFamily(){
         return "myTag.component";
       }

       @Override
       public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
         return;
       }

       @Override
       public void decode(FacesContext context) {
         return;
       } 
     }
   ```
2. Next, we need a taglib XML file, let's call it `mytag.taglib.xml` and put it inside `WEB-INF` dir.

   ```
     <!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
       "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
       "WEB-INF/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd"> 
     <facelet-taglib> 
     <namespace>http://sample.tag/mytags</namespace> 
     <tag>
       <tag-name>myspan</tag-name>
         <component>
           <component-type>myTag.component</component-type>    
         </component>
     </tag>
     </facelet-taglib>
   ```

   Note that:

   - `.taglib.xml` suffix is mandatory
   - `<component-type>` should have the same
     value that is returned by component's `getFamily()` method
   - you can
     replace `WEB-INF/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd` with
     `http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd`
3. It's time to modify web.xml and faces-config.xml.

   Former should be modified with

   ```
   <context-param> 
     <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name> 
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/mytag.taglib.xml</param-value> 
   </context-param>
   ```

   faces-config.xml should get

   ```
   <component> 
    <component-type>myTag.component</component-type> 
    <component-class>sample.mytag.LabelComponent</component-class> 
   </component>
   ```
4. We're good to go!

   ```
       <ui:composition
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  
         xmlns:sample="http://sample.tag/mytag">  

         <sample:myspan text="I'm inside a span!"/>

       </ui:composition>
   ```